# R package for active learning and sampling

Tags: r, active-learning

I tried to find R package for active learning/sampling and stumbled over "activelearning" package. However, this package is not available on CRAN.

- Does someone know how good is this package?
- Are there any other active learning packages available on CRAN?

Comment: Check out this one at github. Also literature available at http://burrsettles.com/pub/settles.activelearning.pdf https://github.com/ramhiser/activelearning